# Error due to same jars in sub-modules

Tags: android, gradle

I am building an apk using gradle which have multiple sub-modules. These sub-modules include few same jars. Due to this its giving error during compilation of my apk.
To be more specific, the same jar is 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' which is included in more than one sub-module. And during my apk compilation, i am getting error:
     com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

I found few similar questions, but still couldn't resolve this error. Please help.

Comment: First thing to do is change the -v4:+ to a specific version. You are always going to have issues being the vague about the version. Use a scalpel, not a shotgun. Could be due to different versions being imported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove those com.android.support:support-v4 jar files and include only com.android.support:support-v4 jar in main application. If required you can copy same jar files in submodules. 
Clean and build, now you check.
[I am using Eclipse hoping that clean n build would also be exist in Android Studio.]